# How to access cookies of publisher's domain when AMP page is served from google

Tags: amp-html

I am using amp-access to authenticate a user on the AMP page. Currently, it is working fine on localhost but if the AMP page is served through google, how can we access the cookies of my domain.
Below is my amp-access implementation:

```
<script id="amp-access" type="application/json">
       {
            "authorization": "//localhost:7070/api/authorization?token=CLIENT_ID(token)&clientId=CLIENT_ID(_domain_fp_id)",
            "noPingback": "true",
            "login": {
              "sign-in": "//localhost:7070/api/login", 
              "sign-out": ""
        },
        "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
            "error":true,
            "success":false
        }

    }
</script>
```